# Android runtime permission call same Fragment after accept or denied permission

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions, android-dialogfragment

Helo guys,

I have activity with component "BottomNavigationView" and in this component I have four fragments. When I click for example on second fragment and click on button "Give permission" here is pop-up for runtime permission for write and read external storage.

When I accept or denied runtime permission application is automatically make callback to MainActivity and show first fragment by default (Because first fragment is default fragment in Main Activitiy).

Is it possible after accept or denied stay on second fragment? Or I need for example save in sharedpreference position of my fragment and invite fragment on this position.

I tried with lib https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions. After un success I tried with custom implementation for permission.

Here is my code.

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 121;
private void requiredUserPermissionForDownloadPDF(){
    if(!permissionAlreadyGranted()){
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}


private boolean permissionAlreadyGranted() {
    String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    for (String permission : perms) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        System.out.println("Granted");
    }
}
```

Is it possible after accept or denied stay on second fragment? Or I need for example save in sharedpreference position of my fragment and invite fragment on this position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, it happens because activity is recreating. 
You have to save selected item id from BottomNavigationView in `onSaveInstanceState` method, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(KEY_BOT_NAV_VIEW_SELECTED_ITEM_ID, mBottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Where `KEY_BOT_NAV_VIEW_SELECTED_ITEM_ID` is string key for saving and retrieving id. Then, after this, when your activity is created again and `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` is called, bundle argument is not null and you can retrieve saved id:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        restoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    } else {
        //show first fragment fragment 
    }
}
```

You can learn more about saving and restoring state from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes will be same effect If I use SavedInstanceState or SharedPreference. But is it not possible without this tips & tricks ? This method onRequestPermissionsResult call Activity. I don't know is it possible to override this method for fragment or it is always call activity.

Comment: if you will use SharedPreference for this purpose, you will not know when to save state, as on destroy will call every time when activity is finished. But when you use onSaveInstanceState - you will know for sure, that there is need to save current fragment

Comment: onSaveInstanceState is designed for this purpose - saving and restoring state when app process is killed or restarted. Take a look into link which I provided there is pretty good explanation about this

Comment: Ok. Thanks for answer :)

Comment: @Mirko, I did not notice your question about onRequestPermissionsResult before. If you call requestPermissions in your Fragment class - you will receive onRequestPermissionsResult in Fragment. Make sure your activity call super.onRequestPermissionsResult if you override it

Comment: Thanks for helping :) I will try with savedInstanceState I think this is good answer for this problem.

Comment: Also works if I removed from MainActivity onResume() method and make all initialization in onCreate() method. And for this case I didn't need savedInstanceState

Comment: I suggest you to add it anyway, from my experience I can say that you will need to do it anyway) small piece of code but app is more stable

Comment: Yes but onCreate() method in MainActivity is not called after I give or denied permission. It is only called method onResume() and onPause()

Answer (score 0):

Are you requesting permission from the second fragment or from the activity? If requesting from the fragment, it stays within the fragment.

Comment: I requesting from fragment. My problem was resolved when I removed onResume() method from MainActivity and do all my job in onCreate() method.